# I am trying to run wmic command for running commands from one computer to another

Tags: python, process, remote-access, access-denied, wmic

I am trying to run following command,
wmic /node:amarpc /user:admin /password:myadmin process call create 'cmd.exe /c "tnsping compote"'

But I faced problem of
Access denied

I tried many ways to resolve but can't get solution

Comment: First, please share the code you are having trouble with, secondly, please post the full error you are getting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.